# Adapter images which are loaded via Fresco library are irregular

Tags: java, fresco

I have been using `fresco` library to load images in the adapter but the images are not set correctly as I expected.
Here is my code:

```
 public class HomeListingAdapter_recyler1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter  {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList propertyItemList;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    public HomeListingAdapter_recyler1(HomeListingActivity_recycler propertyViews, ArrayList propertyItemList) {
        Fresco.initialize(propertyViews);
        this.propertyItemList = propertyItemList;
        this.context = propertyViews;
    }
    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.property_item_layout,parent,false);
        CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        mImageLoader = VolleySingletonPattern.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        holder.txtPropertyName.setText(propertyItemList.get(position).ville);
        holder.txtPropertyType.setText(propertyItemList.get(position).bienName);
        if(propertyItemList.get(position).pieces.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
            holder.txtPropertySurfaceArea.setText(propertyItemList.get(position).surface+" "+context.getString(R.string.meter_square));
        } else {                holder.txtPropertySurfaceArea.setText(propertyItemList.get(position).surface+" "+context.getString(R.string.meter_square)+" - "+ propertyItemList.get(position).pieces+" "+context.getResources().getString(R.string.pieces));
        }
        holder.txtPropertyPrice.setText(propertyItemList.get(position).montantLoyer);
        Uri imageUri;
        try {
            if(!TextUtils.isNullOrEmpty(propertyItemList.get(position).photo)) {
                imageUri = Uri.parse(propertyItemList.get(position).photo);
                holder.imgPropertyImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.imgPropertyImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return propertyItemList.size();
    }
    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        SimpleDraweeView imgPropertyImage;
        public TextView txtPropertyName , txtPropertyType , txtPropertySurfaceArea ,txtPropertyPrice;
        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgPropertyImage = (SimpleDraweeView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_property);
            txtPropertyName = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_property_name);
            txtPropertyType = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_property_type);
            txtPropertySurfaceArea = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_property_surface_piece);
            txtPropertyPrice = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_property_price);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let us know what you expected the output to be versus what it actually was. Since this is a graphics/UI question, including a screenshot might help people figure out what is wrong.

Comment: hi,  Henrik Gustafsson! thanks for your reply. Actually the text data have been set correctly in the corresponding position of the listview, but the images are not setting in the right position and so many duplicates are there.Each time when i scroll the listview, it sets different images in the item. i have attached the  screen shots. 
1) http://www.mediafire.com/view/bmkhrry9149p43r/fresco3.png
2) http://www.mediafire.com/view/afxzut3fdp5rbk2/fresco2.png
3) http://www.mediafire.com/view/ek1w1tmx8v3wa7m/fresco1.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your default place holder image in xml. In your adapter class if your photo url is not empty, convert your photo url string as uri and set it as view.setImageUri(uri), else set view.setImageUri(null) in your else part.

```
Uri imageUri;

try {

holder.imgPropertyImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

if(!TextUtils.isNullOrEmpty(propertyItemList.get(position).photo)) {

imageUri = Uri.parse(propertyItemList.get(position).photo);

holder.imgPropertyImage.invalidate();

holder.imgPropertyImage.setImageURI(imageUri);

}

else{

 holder.imgPropertyImage.invalidate();

 holder.imgPropertyImage.setImageURI(null);

 }

 } 
catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

}
```